# Embedded website inside windows app

Tags: .net

How can I have an embedded website inside a windows app and also have it so that the windows app would startup the web server and go to the default page of the website?

Can I use the webdev server that comes with .NET framework?  Or is there something better out there?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want an embedded web server and an embedded web browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host full ASP.NET runtime inside pretty much any .NET application. See [ApplicationHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationhost.aspx):

> Enables hosting of ASP.NET pages outside the Internet Information Services (IIS) application. This class enables the host to create application domains for processing ASP.NET requests.

To display a web page, you can drop a [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w290k23d.aspx) control onto your form, optionally provide an [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) and you're all set.

Comment: You'll need a bunch of socket-handling code to make that work. Best to leverage Cassini.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the standard WebBrowser control to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cassini (the embedded web server) combined with the WebBrowser control is probably your best bet.